# Front loading washer leveled but acts out of balance

Tags: washing-machine

My front loading washing machine is acting out of balance. It's not too bad when spinning empty but if there are clothes in it, it rocks and makes loud squeaking noises. I've leveled it, front to back and side to side are within level using a 4' bubble level.  When it's spinning I can see that the drum moves front to back relative to the door.

Can I open it and re-level the drum?  Any idea how to level the drum?

Comment: Have you tried this with no load?

Comment: Is it still under warranty?  If so then definitely contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is no longer under warranty. We just moved and I'm afraid something may have happened while moving. With no load it spins fine and is quiet.

Answer (score 2):

Should have mentioned the washer is mounted on a pedestal.  It seems the screws holding it to the pedestal needed to be tightened.  It's working fine now.

Thanks for the help.